# How to stop button inside form tags from submitting data

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I'm trying to make a form taking input of numbers, inside the form I have on input field but with some button for styling the said field, and an anchor tag to send the form to a php file. Clicking one of the buttons send the current value immediately, how to stop that ?

```
<form name="destination" action="../a.php" method="post">
    Quantity : 
    <button onclick="dec('amount')">-</button>
    <input name="amount" type="text" value="0" size = 1>
    <button onclick="inc('amount')">+</button><br><br>
    </form>
<a href="javascript:submitForm()">Details</a>
```

Buttons JS :

```
function inc(element) {
    let el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
    el.value = parseInt(el.value) + 1;
  }
  
  function dec(element) {
    let el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
      if (parseInt(el.value) > 0) {
        el.value = parseInt(el.value) - 1;
    }
  }
```

Anchor tag JS function:

````
function submitForm() {
document.destination.submit();
}
</script>```
````

Comment: the button type needs to be defined `<button type='button'` otherwise it will get defaulted to a `type='submit'` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms

Comment: @Kinglish is correct. But also, a `onclick` function passes an `event` object down to the function, and you could do `event.preventDefault()` and this would stop any default behavior from happening like opening a link or submitting a form.  [preventDefault Doc](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do easily, just include `event.preventDefault()` in your js code.

`event.preventDefault()` actually used to prevent(stop) any default event.

```
function inc(element) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
  el.value = parseInt(el.value) + 1;
}

function dec(element) {
 event.preventDefault();
 let el = document.querySelector(`[name="${element}"]`);
  if (parseInt(el.value) > 0) {
    el.value = parseInt(el.value) - 1;
  }
}
```

But in case you don't want to use js, you can change buttons default type.
Button's default type is `submit` which will submit the form. You can use `type="button"`

Comment: Thanks all of you guys, you saved me :D

Comment: @Rosalyo that's why we are here.

Comment: No need for js, look at my answer for my explanation

Answer (score 0):

In html the button's default type id "submit" which will submit forms. To avoid this behavior simply assign a different type

```
<button type="button">...</button>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_button_type.asp